# create-react-native-app (with expo) takes 16 seconds to update on each save. very slow workflow

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion, expo, create-react-native-app

Currently the official Getting started of react native is using crna (create-react-native-app) which is bundled with expo. Although I LOVE expo features, I'm trying to run a simple example and the update time on each save takes 16 seconds. 16 seconds update is impossible to work with, so I must be missing something. I made sure I have the latest node.js version, the latest npm version, the latest Expo XDE which I thought will help....
I am running on Windows on a brand new Dell power laptop. I tried using my Android device and also tried using Genymotion.
Results are the same - 16 seconds to update the screen on the simplest change.
How long does it suppose to take to update and what do I need to configure in order to achieve a reasonable update time?

Answer (score 0):

Enable [hot reload](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html). This should speed up the process.

In order to activate it, shake your device to access the menu (real device), or press + in genymotion.

It has some issues, like when you update assets, that force you to do a complete restart with the "Restart" button in the expo xde, still it works most of the time.